# How post json data without column names using webapi?

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I had method to post the json data using webpi, but when data data is pushing from mobile application in json format without columns names , how can I receive that and post in database in webapi?
Is it possible to that?
I am receiving data in below format?

{
             "12122",
             "2000",
           "",
             "17.3660°N",
           "15",
            "56654",
             "cash",
            "",
            "78.4760°E"
        }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're receiving a JSON serialized collection of strings.
As long as you can guarantee the order, you *could* do something like this.

In your controller, have your POST method accept an array of strings as the type, and traverse it with the index.

```
    public HttpResponseMessage Post(string[] data)
    {
        var col1 = data[0];
        var col2 = data[2];
    }
```